# moving text in radio button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

How can I simply move the text so it does not continue below the `<input>` field, without making a `<div>` wrap the text?

[image]

currently, my HTML is as:

```
<div class="answer">
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="a_0" name="a" value="86692726-ff5a-4f1f-b2f4-51a98e03eba0">
        Designer Brille Mode – Brille forum på Trendsales</label>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="a_1" name="a" value="98f07484-5e65-47fc-bb46-b9a59125bdd2">
        Design by Me – unika og hjemmelavede annoncer på Trendsales</label>
</div>
<div class="control-group">
    <label class="radio">
        <input type="radio" id="a_2" name="a" value="248e7343-ddf7-4d61-94fa-e5425fa5f54b">
        Dansk Børne Mode på Trendsales</label>
</div>
</div>
```

And I'm using [Bootstrap CSS Framework](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms), a **Live example** can be [found in JsBin](http://jsbin.com/epagep/1/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First step: don't wrap the `input` with `label`.

Second step: change the default `display` for `input` & `label` to `block`, set `width` and `float them`.

So the CSS will be something like:

```
.answer {width:200px;overflow:hidden;}
input,label {display:block;float:left}
input {clear:left;width:16px;}
label {width:184px;}
```

**Demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/6v8Dc/

Comment: I did mention: `without making a <div> wrap the text` you're using a `<span>` with `display:block` witch is the same... I ony want to mess up with CSS, do not want to mess up with the HTML.

Comment: @balexandre where do I use `span`? The HTML changes I made was to add `input` and `label` side by side.

Comment: you are wrapping with `<label class="radio">` (at least moving it from wrapping the `input` as well) and you didn't even load Bootstrap library as you breaking it's form set.

Comment: @balexandre this is the semantic way of doing it correct and working. It's your choice what to do. Regarding Bootstrap is your responsibility to provide a demo of the issue you face. Applying the principles of my answer to your example it will work.

Comment: can't change the HTML under a campaign :( need to wait to the campaign end, as CSS are under Amazon S3, it's just replace the file... that's why I wanted to only use CSS to do this. But thanks for the input, I will change the HTML accordingly and upload to the production server soon the campaign ends. **Regarding the demo**, you can see the live example in the bottom of my question, under [JsBin](http://jsbin.com/epagep/1/) (as I dont really like JsFiddle).

Answer (score 0):

`&nbsp;` instead of regular space or [`display: inline-block;`](http://robertnyman.com/2010/02/24/css-display-inline-block-why-it-rocks-and-why-it-sucks/)

Answer (score 0):

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/9e4G3Oji)***

Hi now used to `white-space nowrap` as like this

```
.control-group {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

***[Demo](http://tinkerbin.com/9e4G3Oji)***

Comment: The idea is to `wrap` the text but the 2nd line should not start from the bottom of the `radio` button, but below the start of text on that line. I do not want a `nowrap` as I need the space of the right side of that block.